# Applescript: "key code" command not working

Tags: macos, applescript, evernote

I'm trying to run a code to open an app and execute a keyboard shortcut while in it. When I try to run the code, I receive a message saying: 'Expected end of line but found property' while highlighting the "key". Is the "key code" registering as two different commands?

```
tell application "Evernote"
activate

tell application "Evernote" keycode 45 using {command down, shift down}

end tell
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to invoke "System Events" to use UI scripting.

```
tell application "Evernote"
    activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Evernote" to key code 45 using {command down, shift down}
    end tell
end tell
```

More info at http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html

Answer (score 3):

`key code` belongs to `System Events` and consists of two words

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 45 using {command down, shift down}
```

As keystrokes are always sent to the frontmost application it's actually not needed to refer to the target process when it has been explicitly made active.